# Different Outputs_networking

Tags: java

[image]

```
import java.net.*;
 class check {
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
   InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   System.out.println(address);
 }
}
```

**Now the first output is when i am connected to internet and second output is when i am not connected to internet.**
*What type of ip address is the second one? (the one encapsulated in InetAddress with internet not working)*

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. It's always present on your computer. When you don't have an externally accessible IP assigned to your machine, that's your local address.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is available, whether you connected to the internet / intranet or not. But it's the least interesting of addresses, so `getLocalHost()` only returns it as a last resort.

Comment: @Brian Roach will it be same on every pc?

Comment: @9000 - Which is what "always present" means.

Comment: @Suhail - Yes. Every machine will have 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Brian-Roach: the comment was for the benefit of the original poster. I'm sure that _you_ know about localhost :)

Comment: @Brian Roach what is the significance of this address?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the canonical [loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback_address), in short, it's an always-available address of your own machine.

Actually, just googling this address brings relevant info instantly.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the default loopback address of  any machine when its no assigned particular ip